# uid 1 super user - what is is for

Tags: users

There is Drupal super user with uid = 1. I was trying to find out what is so special about this account and what activities will require this account. Is it necessary to have access to this account for Drupal page administration. I would like to know a list of thing that will require super user access. I would also like to know what is so special about this account. As far as I know there can be only one super user in Drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drupal user with uid = 1 is created by Drupal during the installation process of Drupal. User 1 bypasses all `access callbacks` in the system by default -- he can see/do anything.

Beyond that it is a typical Drupal user. If you want to secure the "admin" or uid=1 user please [refer to this documentation page: Securing user #1](https://drupal.org/node/947312) on steps you can take to secure the usage of the uid=1 user.

Comment: Not quite true! User 1 is only granted unconditional access through [`user_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/7) (which happens to be the default `access callback` for a router item). If a different `access callback` is specified it's up to the function to decide whether user 1 gets access. A great example is `/user/login`..user 1 can't access that because the access callback is `user_is_anonymous`

Comment: @Clive, yes I've seen this to on custom access callbacks. I think for brevity of explanation the linked docs page dumbs it down. If you'd like to recommend an Edit for that page go for it :)